# Вывести данные mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ребят подскажите как реализовать, есть у меня в бд записи, все выводятся списком через php на сайт. Есть у меня так же определенная запись со значением допустим 1.

Как мне в списке вывести все, но что бы запись со значением 1 была в начале всего списка.

Пример:

Моя запись со значением 1
Обычная запись со значением 0
Обычная запись со значением 0
Обычная запись со значением 0
и т.д.

Сейчас же моя запись со значением не выводится в начале списка, она выводится исходя из id записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгих попыток узнать, что нужно автору:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `field_1` DESC, `field_2` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать сортировку в обратном порядке:

```
SELECT * FROM `ваша таблица` ORDER By `колонка в которой 0 или 1` DESC;
```

Comment: Не совсем хорошее решение, есть ли что то более лучше?

Comment: @keaks88 Не очень понятно. Вам нужно, чтобы первыми выводились записи у которого определенное поле содержит '1', а потом '0'. Это и делается сортировкой. Либо сортируйте уже на уровне PHP, но лучше конечно на mysql.

Comment: Мне именно как раз нужна сортировка, mysql да это отлично. Вы не знаете более лучший вариант того что написали выше?

Comment: @keaks88 Почему Вам не подошел предложенный вариант? Он делает то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать так, выводить так же как в предложеном варианте, но что бы строки с одним и с другим значением выводились по алфавиту ASС но так же что бы были вверху со значением 1